por qué se me cierra cuando le doy click a algun item de mi ListView en android studio
****SECCIONES QUE TENGO**

Al darle click a algun item de mi listview donde muestro una lista de estudiantes, la app se me cierra
he revisado la logica que lleva mi codigo, pero de hecho no me marca el error. Me gustaria saber en que puedo estar fallando. Gracias de antemano!`"MAIN"package com.mipaquete.app_notas**
`import Clases_Activity
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
    import android.widget.ListView
    import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
    import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
    import com.mipaquete.app_notas.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            enableEdgeToEdge()
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
                val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
                v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
                insets
            }
    
            binding.listView1.adapter = Adapter_Estudiante(this, DatosGlobales.estudiantes)
    
            binding.listView1.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
                val i: Intent = Intent(this, Clases_Activity::class.java)
                val estudianteSeleccionado = DatosGlobales.estudiantes[position]
                //obteniendo las clases
                i.putExtra("clase1", estudianteSeleccionado.clase1)
                i.putExtra("clase2", estudianteSeleccionado.clase2)
                i.putExtra("clase3", estudianteSeleccionado.clase3)
                i.putExtra("clase4", estudianteSeleccionado.clase4)
                i.putExtra("clase5", estudianteSeleccionado.clase5)
                i.putExtra("clase6", estudianteSeleccionado.clase6)
                //obteniendo las notas
                i.putExtra("nota1", estudianteSeleccionado.nota1)
                i.putExtra("nota2", estudianteSeleccionado.nota2)
                i.putExtra("nota3", estudianteSeleccionado.nota3)
                i.putExtra("nota4", estudianteSeleccionado.nota4)
                i.putExtra("nota5", estudianteSeleccionado.nota5)
                i.putExtra("nota6", estudianteSeleccionado.nota6)
                startActivity(i)
            }
        }
    }
    /**********************************ADAPTER*************************************************/
    package com.mipaquete.app_notas
    
    import android.content.Context
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
    import android.widget.TextView
    
    class Adapter_Estudiante(context: Context, val valores: List<Alumno>) : ArrayAdapter<Alumno>(context, 0, valores){
    
        //Sobreescribimos el metodo getview
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    
            //definimos la vista del elemento
            var itemview = convertView
            //inflamos
            if (itemview == null)
                itemview = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false)
    
            //Obtenemos el elemento de la lista
            val alumno = valores[position]
    
            //personsalizamos la vista
            itemview!!.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1).setText("Nombres: "+ alumno.nombrealumno)
            itemview!!.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text2).setText("Apellidos: " +alumno.apellidoalumno)
    
            return itemview!!
        }
    }
    /***********************************ACTIVITY CLASES(DONDE MUESTRO LAS CLASE)*************************************************/
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.net.Uri
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
    import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
    import com.mipaquete.app_notas.DatosGlobales
    import com.mipaquete.app_notas.Notas_Activity
    import com.mipaquete.app_notas.R
    import com.mipaquete.app_notas.databinding.ActivityClasesBinding
    
    class Clases_Activity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityClasesBinding
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            //guardando las notas recibidas del Main activity
            val nota1 = intent.getStringExtra("nota1")
            val nota2 = intent.getStringExtra("nota2")
            val nota3 = intent.getStringExtra("nota3")
            val nota4 = intent.getStringExtra("nota4")
            val nota5 = intent.getStringExtra("nota5")
            val nota6 = intent.getStringExtra("nota6")
            //Configurando el click de cada boton
            binding.btnClase1.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, Notas_Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("numeroClase", 1)
                intent.putExtra("nota1", nota1)
                startActivity(intent)
            }``your text``
            binding.btnClase2.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, Notas_Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("numeroClase", 2)
                intent.putExtra("nota2", nota2)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            binding.btnClase3.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, Notas_Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("numeroClase", 3)
                intent.putExtra("nota3", nota3)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            binding.btnClase4.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, Notas_Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("numeroClase", 4)
                intent.putExtra("nota4", nota4)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            binding.btnClase5.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, Notas_Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("numeroClase", 5)
                intent.putExtra("nota5", nota5)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            binding.btnClase6.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, Notas_Activity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("numeroClase", 6)
                intent.putExtra("nota6", nota6)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            enableEdgeToEdge()
            binding = ActivityClasesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
                val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
                v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
                insets
    
            }
            //le paso los valores de la lista a los botones del activity clases
    
            binding.btnClase1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("clase1"))
            binding.btnClase2.setText(intent.getStringExtra("clase2"))
            binding.btnClase3.setText(intent.getStringExtra("clase3"))
            binding.btnClase4.setText(intent.getStringExtra("clase4"))
            binding.btnClase5.setText(intent.getStringExtra("clase5"))
            binding.btnClase6.setText(intent.getStringExtra("clase6"))
    
        }
    }
    
    
****SECCIONES QUE TENGO**

Al darle click a algun item de mi listview donde muestro una lista de estudiantes, la app se me cierra
he revisado la logica que lleva mi codigo, pero de hecho no me marca el error. Me gustaria saber en que puedo estar fallando. Gracias de antemano!`"MAIN"package com.mipaquete.app_notas**

Incluye el error que te aparece en logcat

En el logCat solo cuando conecto el celular me aparece informacion, pero con el emulador de android studio no me aparece. Adjunto el link del repositorio, donde se ve mas detallada la informacion>>>>> https://github.com/cristophersilva17/APP_Notas
